# Fastest way (in performance terms) for COM events handling

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, com, event-handling, atl

I have COM Quote class with dispinterface _QuoteEvents. For event handling I use following instructions:

Event sink class, derived from IDispEventSimpleImpl:

```
class CProxyQuoteEvents : public IDispEventSimpleImpl<SINK_ID, CProxyQuoteEvents, &__uuidof(_IQuoteEvents)> {
....
}
```

COM library initialization and objects creation and advising:

```
CProxyQuoteEvents g_quoteEventsProxy;
QuotePtr g_quote;

CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
g_quote.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Quote));
g_quoteEventsProxy.DispEventAdvise(g_quote, &__uuidof(_IQuoteEvents));
```

All these constructions works fine for me (events handles as expected), but I want to know is there any other faster solution? Maybe I can realize it without ATL if avoiding ATL will be faster?

Also please explain if there is difference between

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CSimple : 
public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
public CComCoClass<CSimple, &CLSID_Simple>,
public IDispatchImpl<ISwitch, &IID_ISwitch, &LIBID_DISPEVENTLib>,
public IDispEventSimpleImpl</*nID =*/ 1, CSimple, &__uuidof(Word::ApplicationEvents)>
```

and

```
class CSimple :    
public IDispEventSimpleImpl</*nID =*/ 1, CSimple, &__uuidof(Word::ApplicationEvents)>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most consuming part of dispatching events with this code snippet is the delivery using `IDispatch::Invoke` and it's entirely on the COM server side (especially if COM server resides in a different process, or apartment). There is little you can do unless you are aware of a different event dispatching method this COM server offers, and it's better in terms of latency.

> Also please explain if there is difference between... IDispEventSimpleImpl

There is no difference. It is `IDispEventSimpleImpl` in both cases and it is the class that receives the calls. `IDispEventSimpleImpl` (unlike many other ATL classes) does not need you to implement it on real COM object class, any class will do.